# Accessing Identity UserManager from a custom class within a SignalR hub

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I have a `ChatUser` class that I am trying to initialize from within a SignalR hub.  One of the properties of this class is a custom Identity `ApplicationUser` object.  When I instantiate an instance of `ChatUser`, I also populate this `ApplicationUser` property so that I can access info about the user in my app as shown below:

```
    public ChatUser(int userId)
    {
        ApplicationUser u = UserManager.FindById(userId);
        this.User = u;
    }
```

However, I cannot get the `UserManager` object to instantiate properly inside this class.

Outside of SignalR (for example, in a normal controller), I would normally instantiate `UserManager` with the following code:

```
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    private ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            if (_userManager == null)
            {
                _userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
            if ((_userManager == null) || (_userManager.IsDisposed == true))
            {
                _userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new CustomUserStore(new ApplicationDbContext()));
            }
            return _userManager;
        }
        set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
```

However, according to the SignalR documentation, the `HttpContext` object is unreliable (which I have confirmed to be true in this instance) and you should instead use the following:

```
 _userManager = Context.Request.GetHttpContext().GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
```

This does work correctly inside the Hub.  I've tried to find how to make this `Context` object available in my custom class, but cannot identify the proper process.  I've tried the guidance given here to access a Hub from outside the Hub:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#how-to-call-client-methods-and-manage-groups-from-outside-the-hub-class

```
 IHubContext ChatHubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
```

However, this is not the correct "context" as this gives a `IHubContext` object which only has properties of `Groups` and `Clients`.

Is it possible to access the proper context object that exposes the `Request.GetHttpContext...` methods?

Comment: If you are on .NET core you can use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48087874/1938988)