# .Net Core IdentityServer4 Get Authenticated User

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve a logged in user from Identity server 4 using .Net-Core 2.    My authentication is working currently, I'm just trying to figure out how I can retrieve the claims Identity from the HTTP Context.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddIdentityServerAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.Authority = IDP_AUTHORITY_URL;
    o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    o.ApiName = API_ID;
    o.JwtBearerEvents = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnTokenValidated = async tokenValidationContext =>
        {
            var claimsIdentity = tokenValidationContext.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            if (claimsIdentity == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            string userId = claimsIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "sub").Value;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
            {
                throw new AuthenticationException("Error obtaining Subject claim");
            }
        }
    };
});
```

I have a service which I require the logged in user I can't figure out how to get it.

```
public interface IAuthenticatedUserManager<T>
    where T: class
{
    T GetLoggedInUser();
}

public class AuthenticatedUserManager : IAuthenticatedUserManager<User>
{
    public User GetLoggedInUser()
    { 
        //HttpContext.Current
    }
}
```

It use to be on the HttpContext.Current, but I do not see that as an option in .Net-Core 2.  How can I retreive my ClaimsIdentity from .Net Core 2?

Comment: Have you seen `HttpContext.User.Identity`? It sounds like that's what you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks I’ll check that when I get home!

Comment: @NeilBostian is that an Instance Of an HttpContext?  I am not using a Controller.  I was attempting on the Static Method,  Is the HttpContext Injectable by default? How can I get an instance of the httpcontext

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out how to do this.  Since, I am using a custom service which needs the HttpContext Injected into it I needed to register an accessor as injectable:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Then in my Authentication Manager I can Access my HttpContext

```
public class UserAuthenticationManager : IUserAuthenticationManager
{
    HttpContext _httpContext;

    public UserAuthenticationManager(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this._httpContext = httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext;
    }
    public ClaimsIdentity GetClaimsIdentity()
    {
        return (this._httpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This should work for you:

```
var user = (HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);
```

And then the *user* object has what you need.

Comment: is that an Instance Of an HttpContext? I am not using a Controller. I was attempting on the Static Method, Is the HttpContext Injectable by default? How can I get an instance of the httpcontext

Comment: @johnny5 it supposed to be this `var user = Context.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;`